# How to charge data in a summernote with meteor JS?

Tags: javascript, web, meteor, summernote

Im using meteor JS and try to implement a summernote.
The problem is, when i try to open a summernote with my data, it work just sometimes.
when i charge the page for the first time, nothing appears in the summernote, but if i change something in my code and save it, the content will appear in the summernote.
please, help me :'(

```
<template name="consigneModif">
  <div class="container">
    <div class = "col text-center">
      <h1>Modification de {{{this.Name}}}</h1>
    </div> 
    <form class="formConsigne">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Description"><h4>Nom :</h4></label>
        <textarea class="summernote" id="Name" name="Name">{{{this.Name}}}</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Description"><h4>Description :</h4></label>
        <textarea class="summernote" id="Description" name="Description" rows="3">{{{this.Description}}}</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Condition"><h4>Condition d'application de la consigne : </h4></label>
        <textarea class="summernote" id="Condition" name = "Condition" rows="3">{{{this.Condition}}}</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Mode"><h4>Mode opératoire :</h4></label>
        <textarea class="summernote" id="Mode" name ="Mode" rows="3">{{{this.Mode}}}</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Date"><p>Date effective :</p></label>
        <input type="Date" id="Date" name = Date>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="DateFin"><p>Date de fin :</p></label>
        <input type="Date" id="DateFin" name = DateFin>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" class ="btn btn-success" id="AddConsignButton">Modifier</button>
      </div>
    </form>     
  </div>
  {{>footerNavbar}}
  <script>
    $('.summernote').summernote('code');
</script>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the `script` tag you are using to activate the summernote. It should work if you use the [`onRender`](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-onRendered) method of the template instead.

This may work:

```js
Template.consigneModif.onRendered(function () {
  this.$('.summernote').summernote('code');
});
```

Comment: mmm, it doest work, i have finally found a solution, but i dont know why it work. I just delete the target attribute to my button, who allows me to go on the template "consigneModif". i don't open a new window, but this is better for my application. BUt i really dont understand why it work now.